# Create a calculated field to count dimension on a condition in Tableau

Tags: tableau-api

[image: tableau]

I have two dimensions (Case Numbers, Test Code) and I want to count only the Case Numbers which have both test codes i.e. 4802 & 9050.

Comment: Hi Syed! welcome to stack overflow.  which version of tableau are you using?  One more thing do the field `Testcode` have values other than 4802 &/or 9050?

Comment: Please read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and update your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a data similar to yours

[image]

Create this calculated field

```
{FIXED [CaseNumber]: sum(
IF [TestCode] = '4802' OR [TestCode] = '9050' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)} = 2
```

`TRUE` in above calculated field will return only desired `CaseNumbers`.  Check

[image]

OR

[image]

OR

[image]

Comment: Equivalently, 
{ FIXED [CaseNumber] : MAX([TestCode] = '4802') AND MAX([TestCode] = '9050') }